# How to have a combined legend for colors and marker types

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, errorbar

I frequently generate complex plots and strive to simplify the legends. In this particular instance, I am plotting data categorized by multiple models and temperature bands. I want to include two distinct and simplified legends with filled markers while the plot has unfilled markers, but I am facing a challenge: modifying the marker for the legend also alters the markers in the plot.

The only approach I have found to produce the desired legends is to copy the plot handles and modify the marker in the copy using copy.deepcopy(). However, this method creates additional copies of the figure and the plot with some of the markers using the modified symbols, which is not ideal.

I am seeking a more elegant solution to generate the plot and legends without these drawbacks. As a beginner in Python, I am open to learning new techniques. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or if I need to provide further details or images.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
from matplotlib import container
import copy
%matplotlib tk

# Read data
df_main  = pd.read_csv(outputfile_head_tail,index_col=0)

# Indices by Model
base = df_main.index.str.contains("Base")
p90 = df_main.index.str.contains("90")
p80 = df_main.index.str.contains("80")
p70 = df_main.index.str.contains("70")

# Calculate plot values
df_main['dt_h'] = abs(df_main['ti_input'] - df_main['this_ave'])
df_main['dt_cv'] = abs(df_main['to_input'] - df_main['ti_input'])

# Plot presets
fontsize = 24
marker_edge_width = 2
marker_size = 10
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = fontsize
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
plt.rcParams["font.serif"] = ["Times New Roman"] + plt.rcParams["font.serif"]
colors = ['brown','r','g', 'b','k', 'orange', 'teal', 'm']
symbols = ['o','v','P','D','*', 'p','X', 's','>', 'h','<', 'd','^']

# Temperature Bands
bands = [273,373,473,573,673]

# Containers for Making Legends
color_collection = []
type_legend_handle = []
type_legend_lable = []
marker_collection = []
temp_legend_handle = []
temp_legend_label = []

# Make 1 figures with corresponding plots
fig1, dThvsdTcv = plt.subplots()
fig1.set_size_inches(14,10,forward=True)

# Model selector
selector = ['base', 'p90', 'p80', 'p70']

# Color is assigned based on Model
for type,color in zip(selector,colors):
    df = df_main.loc[locals()[type]]

    # Marker Shapes are assigned based on Temperature Bands
    for idx, band in enumerate(bands):
        marker = symbols[idx]
        
        # Select Cases that are ±50K of the Temperature Band
        if df.loc[(df['to_input'] > band-50) & (df['to_input'] <= band+50)].shape[0]!=0:

            # Generate pltkwargs
            pltkwargs       = dict(linestyle=':', color = color,
                                markeredgecolor = color, markeredgewidth = marker_edge_width,
                                marker=marker, markersize=marker_size, fillstyle = 'none', markerfacecolor=color)
            
            # Plot the data and collect plot handle for legend
            leg = dThvsdTcv.errorbar(df.loc[(df['to_input'] > band-50) & (df['to_input'] <= band+50),'dt_cv'], 
                                     df.loc[(df['to_input'] > band-50) & (df['to_input'] <= band+50),'dt_h'], 
                                     label = f'{type}_{band}K', 
                                     **pltkwargs)
            
            # Collect one plot handle and label per markers for each Temperature Band
            if marker not in marker_collection:
                marker_collection.append(marker)
                temp_legend_handle.append(leg)
                temp_legend_label.append(f'{band}')

            # Collect one plot handle and label per color for each Model
            if color not in color_collection:
                color_collection.append(color)
                type_legend_handle.append(leg)
                type_legend_lable.append(f'{type}')

# Use deep copy of the Model plot handels to modify the symbols for the legend. Legend symbols should be filled
th_copy = copy.deepcopy(type_legend_handle)
typehandles = [(h[0]) if isinstance(h,container.ErrorbarContainer) else h for h in th_copy]
for tleg in typehandles:
        tleg.set_fillstyle('full')
        tleg.set_linestyle('None')

# Create a legend using the modified symbols and the collected lables        
typelegend = dThvsdTcv.legend(typehandles,type_legend_lable, loc='lower right', handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})

# The text of the label for the Model Legend has to match the symbol
for idx, tleg_lab in enumerate(typelegend.get_texts()):
    tleg_lab.set_color(colors[idx])
dThvsdTcv.add_artist(typelegend)

# Use a deep copy of the Temperature Bands plot handles to modify symbol fill.
temp_leg_handle_copy = copy.deepcopy(temp_legend_handle)
handles = [(h[0]) if isinstance(h,container.ErrorbarContainer) else h for h in temp_leg_handle_copy]
for leg in handles:
        leg.set_fillstyle('full')          #leg.lines[0].set_fillstyle('full')
        leg.set_markeredgecolor('k')       #leg.lines[0].set_markeredgecolor('k')
        leg.set_markerfacecolor('k')       #leg.lines[0].set_markerfacecolor('k')
        leg.set_linestyle('None')        
dThvsdTcv.legend(handles,temp_legend_label, loc = 'upper left')

dThvsdTcv.set_ylabel(r'$ΔT_h[K]$')
dThvsdTcv.set_xlabel(r'$ΔT_{CV}[K]$')
fig1.tight_layout()`
```

[image: Plot with legends]

I tried to modify the markers after plotting the data. I was expecting that this would not affect the markers in the plot but it did. So I used copy.deepcopy() to copy the legend and then modify it. This unfortunately makes a copy of the figure also. I tried copy.copy() and that doesn't work as in it shows the modified markers in the plot itself.

Answer (score 2):

The code below creates a similar aesthetic using a call to `seaborn`:

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.relplot(df, x='deltaCV', y='deltaT', hue='selector', style='temp_band',
                 markers=True, dashes=False, errorbar=None,
                 height=5, aspect=1.5, kind='line')
```

Mock data in a tidy format:

```
import pandas as pd

x = np.concatenate([
    np.linspace(5, 95, 30),
])

y_base = x * 2.5 + 70
len_y = len(y_base)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'deltaCV': np.tile(x, 11),
     'deltaT': np.concatenate([y_base,
                               y_base - 5,
                               y_base - 15,
                               y_base - 20,
                               y_base - 30,
                               y_base - 45,
                               y_base - 50,
                               y_base - 65,
                               y_base - 85,
                               y_base - 95,
                               y_base - 110]),
     'selector': ['base']*len_y + ['p90']*len_y + ['base']*len_y +  ['p80']*len_y + ['p90']*len_y +\
                   ['p70']*len_y +  ['p80']*len_y + ['p70']*len_y + ['p90']*len_y +  ['p80']*len_y + ['p70']*len_y,
     'temp_band': [673]*len_y + [673]*len_y + [473]*len_y + [673]*len_y + [573]*len_y +\
                          [373]*len_y + [473]*len_y + [673]*len_y + [373]*len_y + [673]*len_y + [473]*len_y 
    }
)
```

[image]